# React Native - Horizontal Flatlist scrollToTop implementation

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, use-ref, flatlist

In the horizontal flatlist given below:

when I click on the second product Item (which is only slightly visible and contains all the product details), my second product should scrollToTop such that it should be visible fully. How should I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollToIndex` method like this example:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const flatListRef = useRef();
  const data = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy',
      body: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy',
      body: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    },
  ];

  const scrollToTop = idx => {
    flatListRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({
      animated: true,
      index: idx,
      viewOffset: 100,
    });
  };

  const renderProductCard = ({item, index}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.productCard}
      onPress={() => {
        scrollToTop(index);
        /*        const productCard = [...listDataSource];
                productCard[item.key].isExpanded = !productCard[item.key].isExpanded;
                setListDataSource(productCard);*/
      }}>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        horizontal
        ref={flatListRef}
        contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={renderProductCard}
        keyExtractor={itemData => itemData.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  productCard: {
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    marginRight: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 12,
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! This is calling scrollTo function even the idx value is coming correct but still, it is not working.

Comment: Can I see your code?

Comment: const renderProductCard = ({ item, index }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.productCard}
      onPress={() => {
        scrollToTop(index);
        const productCard = [...listDataSource];
        productCard[item.key].isExpanded = !productCard[item.key].isExpanded;
        setListDataSource(productCard);
      }}
    >
</TouchableOpacity>

Comment: <FlatList
            data={productCards}
            horizontal
            ref={flatListRef}
            keyExtractor={(items) => items.key}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            renderItem={renderProductCard}
            contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }}
          />

Comment: const scrollToTop = (index) => {
    flatListRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({
      animated: true,
      index,
      viewOffset: 100,
    });
  };

Comment: I just updated my answer with a working example from your code samples.